# Google app engine datastore timeout on admin task

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have created a backend for my google app that looks like this:

```
backends:
- name: dbops
  options: dynamic
```

and I've created an admin handler for it:

```
- url: /backend/.*
  script: backend.app
  login: admin
```

Now I understand that admin jobs should be able to run forever and I'm launching this job with a TaskQueue, but for some reason mine is not.  My job is simply creating a summary table in datastore from a much larger table.  This table holds about 12000 records and it takes several minutes for it to process the job on the development server, but it works fine.  When I push the code out to appspot and try to get it to run the same job, I'm getting what looks like datastore timeouts.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myzencoder/dbops.362541511260492787/backend.py", line 626, in get
    for asset in assets:
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2314, in next
    return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2816, in next
    next_batch = self.__batcher.next()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2678, in next
    return self.next_batch(self.AT_LEAST_ONE)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2715, in next_batch
    batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2452, in __query_result_hook
    self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
Timeout: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
```

Anyone got any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the backend request can run for a long time, a query can only run for 60 sec.  You'll have to loop over your query results with cursors.

Mapreduce will get you a result quicker by doing the queries in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

In production you use the HR datastore and you can run into contention problems. See  this article.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention?hl=nl

And have a look at mapreduce for creating a report. Maybe this is a better solution.